# Multiple antMatchers in Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I work on content management system, that has five *antMatchers* like the following:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/*.html").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/admin/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/user/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
```

which suppose to mean that the visitors can see all site at root path (/*), and users can see only (/user), admin can see only (/admin), and there are two login pages one for users and another for admin.

The code seems to work fine, except the admin section - it doesn't work but  return access denied exception.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

I believe that the problem is in the **order** of your rules:

```
.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
.antMatchers("/admin/login").permitAll()
```

The order of the rules matters and the more specific rules should go first. Now everything that starts with `/admin` will require authenticated user with ADMIN role, even the `/admin/login` path (because `/admin/login` is already matched by the `/admin/**` rule and therefore the second rule is ignored).

The rule for the login page should therefore go before the `/admin/**` rule.  E.G.

```
.antMatchers("/admin/login").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

Comment: gotta love order-dependent configuration code :)