# Access denied on jdbc-authentication with any user [OAUTH2]

Tags: java, authentication, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, authorization

I have a jdbc-authentication with an oauth2-authorization in my Spring-Boot Application.
Here is my code for the **jdbc-authentication**:

```
auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
      .usersByUsernameQuery(
       "select username, password, 1 from users where username = ?") 
      .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
       "select u.username, r.name from users u, roles r, role_users ru "
       + "where u.username = ? and u.id =  ru.users_id  and ru.roles_id = r.id ");
```

and my authorization configuration looks like this:

```
http.
    anonymous().disable()
    .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/v1/users/**")
    .and().authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/v1/users/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
```

Now when i authenticate with a user in my database, everything goes fine. I authenticate with a user who has a role **"ADMIN"** and so i think it should allow me to access the `/api/v1/users/**` resource.

But all i get is an `access_denied` error. what am i doing wrong? Let me know if you have to see more code snippets. I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 1):

not a big expert but I never used the method **access(...)**

Have you tried with hasRole ?

something like

```
.antMatchers("/api/v1/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

Comment: your case seems similar to this one: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-security-4-authenticate-and-authorize-users take a look at the httpsecurity config, even the order of rules matters (as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819337/multiple-antmatcher-in-spring-security)

Comment: somehow the `/api/v1/users/**` endpoint doesn't work. I changed it to `/api/v1/users` and now the access is granted. But unfortunately for all users (also those who has not the "ADMIN" role).