# url based custom mutiple auth providers calls always one provider only

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have configured multiple custom `auth providers`,using `auth2` and `spring boot`, but it always executes the `CustomInternalAuthenticationProvider` only.can you please explain the how to apply ant matcher rules in order?i have used two `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` classes and one is orderded and one is default.guide me on how to handle the `antmatcher` rules properly?

```java
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig{

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }


    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("@order");
                      http.antMatcher("/../main/**")
                      .requestMatchers()
                      .antMatchers("/","/login*", "/oauth/authorize**","/exit","**/logout")

                  .and().authenticationProvider(daoInternalAuthenticationProvider())
                   .formLogin().loginPage("/login")

                ;
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationProvider daoInternalAuthenticationProvider() throws Exception {

            return new CustomInternalAuthenticationProvider();
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    public static class ApiTokenSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("default");

                  http.antMatcher("/../user/**")
                      .requestMatchers()
                      .antMatchers("/","/login*", "/oauth/authorize**","/exit","**/logout")


                          .and() .authenticationProvider(daoExternalAuthenticationProvider())
               .formLogin().loginPage("/login")

               ;


        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationProvider daoExternalAuthenticationProvider() throws Exception {

            return new CustomExternalAuthonticationProvider();
        }






    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple antMatchers in Spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819337/multiple-antmatchers-in-spring-security)

Comment: nono this is my code not the duplicate one i want to use multiplauth providers for multiple urls and need to by allowing .antMatchers("/","/login*", "/oauth/authorize**","/exit","**/logout")
to all without authenticating otherwise it's getting Full authentication is required to access this resource error,please help me to solve this problem